# Simple proof of Newton identities

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, alternative-proof, symmetric-polynomials

The functions $s_1=x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n$, $s_2=\sum_{i<j} x_ix_j$, $\cdots$, $s_n=x_1x_2\cdots x_n$ are elementary symmetric functions in $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ (or more precisely, *elementary symmetric polynomials*).

There are other natural symmetric functions in $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$:
$$t_1=x_1+\cdots + x_, \hskip5mm t_2=x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots + x_n^2,  \cdots ,t_n=x_1^n+x_2^n+\cdots+x_n^n.$$
The two sets of symmetric functions are related by some identities, known as [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

What are the simple proofs of these Newton identities? How do we prove them with some intuition or motivation?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/844594/84976

Comment: A proof of Newton's identities lies in this question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789246/given-two-algebraic-conjugates-alpha-beta-and-their-minimal-polynomial-find), precisely in the analytic combinatorics of the EXP and LOG maps.